# MongoDB update elements within array

Tags: mongodb

I have a database of users like in the example below and I need to update the city of the user from Bonn to Berlin.

```
{
    "_id" : "Louis",
    "registered" : true,
    "likes" : [
        "tennis",
        "cooking"
    ],
    "addr" : {
        "city" : "Bonn",
        "country" : "Germany"
    }
}
```

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

```
db.users.update( {_id:"Louis"}, {$set:{city:"Berlin"}} )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have quotes around field names in sub-documents

```
db.test.update( {_id : "Louis"}, {$set : {"addr.city" : "Berlin"}})
```

Comment: The answer is uncompleted if you don't say that to access to a field of a subdocument you need to use the dot notation. The question don't have the dot notation in the code.